# How to mock the static property of a class

Tags: jestjs

I have code which looks like this:

```js
function myfunc(injected_class){
  if (injected_class.name == "ThingOne"){
    // do this
  } else if (injected_class.name == "ThingTwo"){
    // do that
  }
  let instance = new injected_class(options)
  instance.some_instance_method()
}
```

I don't want to mock the module for all the different types of injected classes. I want to pass in a mocked class, but this doesn't work:

```js
let mock_some_instance_method = jest.fn()
let mock_injected_class = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    some_instance_method: mock_some_instance_method
  }
})
mock_some_instance_method.name = "ThingOne"

some_module.myfunc(mock_injected_class)
```

This mostly works, but it doesn't override `injected_class.name`. That is always set to `mockConstructor`. How can I override this static property?

Comment: You're setting the name on the method, not the "class". It's unclear what the actual behaviour of the function under test is, but you may not need a Jest mock at all.

Comment: I could create a "real" class in the test and pass that into myfunc, but I wouldn't be able to use jest's tools to verify things like the number of times the class was instantiated with new, or with what options.